# Why CampaignId is not accessible on workbench while querying on lead?

Tags: apex, data-loader, workbench

I am trying to access campaignId field by querying on lead on workbench. But i am unable to do that. Can anyone tell me, why salesforce did'nt provide that access or should I make any settings to access that field?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the CampaignId is not on the Lead record. Because the same Lead (or contact) can be part of multiple campaigns.

So your Lead to Campaign relationship will be on the CampaignMember record.

Try the query like so.

```
SELECT CampaignId,Id,LeadId,ContactId FROM CampaignMember where LeadId = 'xxx'
```